# java generic: Object<String> obj = new Object<~>();

Tags: java, generics

```
Object<String> obj = new Object<~>();
```

I can't understand that "~" what means. I did google search but there are posted wildcard "?" not "~". Can you help me TT?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? <~> is the shorthand form. In IntelliJ, when you click it, it will change to <String>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij IDEA can shorten some constructs on the editor. These are just visual effects, it doesn't change to code. Some of these *compressed* code elements are

- `<~>`
- java-8-style lambda `->` to visually compress single method anonymous classes
- shorter form for @SuppressWarning annotations
- standard getters and setters are displayed as one line methods

The visual sugar has a different color and will expand to the real code when you click on it.

**Further Reading**

- [Folding](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51949740)